# Postgres: Text Search, combining multiple JSONB tsvectors

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, jsonb

In Postgres 10 you can full-text search `JSONB` data structures:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', '{"key":"value1"}'::jsonb);
>>> [tsvector]
>>> 'value1':1
```

*Notice how tsvector only indexed the values of the JSON object (smart)*

Now I want to combine the `tsvector` of multiple `JSONB` fields...
I can do...

```
SELECT to_tsvector('{"key":"value1"}'::JSONB::TEXT || '{"key2":"value2"}'::JSONB::TEXT );
>>> [tsvector]
>>> 'key':1 'key2':3 'value1':2 'value2':4
```

Notice how because I've casted to `TEXT` I'm getting the keys and the values....

I want to combine the output of multiple tsvector() objects - how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that jsonb values can be [concatenated:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
SELECT '{"key":"value1"}'::jsonb || '{"key2":"value2"}'::jsonb AS new_jsonb

              new_jsonb              
-------------------------------------
 {"key": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
(1 row)
```

You do not need to cast them to text:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('{"key":"value1"}'::jsonb || '{"key2":"value2"}'::jsonb );

      to_tsvector      
-----------------------
 'value1':1 'value2':3
(1 row)
```